# How to export a custom model from TensorflowJS to Tensorflow Python

Tags: javascript, python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow.js

I am trying to export a custom model made with **TensorflowJS** to **Tensorflow Python**. The main problem is that **TF.JS** saves two artifacts: **"model-js.json"** and **"model-js.weights.bin"**

I tried importing the JSON:

```py
    with open('model-js/model-js.json') as json_file:
        json_config = str(json.loads(json_file.read())["modelTopology"])
    
    json_config=json_config.replace("'","\"")

    new_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(json_config)
```

But I am getting the next error:

```
~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end
```

So, the line 103 in the Json File is the "N" in the "Null" of:

```
    "config": {
        "batch_input_shape": [
            null,
            128,
            128,
            1
         ],
         "dtype": "float32",
         "sparse": false,
         "name": "conv2d_input"
    }
```

That is later changed **"Null"** for **"None"** when you import the JSON to python.

Why the **TensorflowJS** model artifacts doesnt fit in **Python Tensorflow**?

Other thing is that I dont know how to import the weights in the .bin file. There are some other ways to do that? Or there are other kinds of files that can be exported from **TF.JS**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Formats are totally different, that is never going to work like that

And there is no *offical* way to convert **TFJS Graph Model** to **TF Saved Model** as conversion is one-way in the opposite direction

You might have some luck using a 3rd party conversion tool, check out https://github.com/patlevin/tfjs-to-tf